# comparing mean to specific data value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data frame like this:

```
Date     Process Duration
1/1/2012 xnit     10
1/1/2012 xnit     15
1/1/2012 xnit     20
1/2/2012 telnet   80
1/2/2012 telnet   50
1/2/2012 telnet   40
8/1/2012 ftp      3
8/1/2012 ftp      11
8/1/2012 ftp     12
```

After converint to x<-data.table(x):

I can calculate the mean for each job as this:

```
x<-x[, mean := mean(Duration), by = Process]
```

I like to compare the duration for a particular date Duration to the mean. I tried this:

```
x<-x[, Aug1 := subset(x, Date==as.Date(c("2012-08-01")))$Duration, by = Process]
```

Once I get this value, I was going to compare the Aug1 column against mean for each process to look at the outliers. However, this command is taking a very long time to complete. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you edit your question (and tags) to clarify whether this is in fact a data.table or not?

Comment: How are you planning to compare? and What doe you expect that final line of code to return? I think you may want to add a month column then use `by=month` but I really don't understand what you're hoping to do.  Can you include your expected output of the last line of code as well as your final desired result?

Comment: There is no need to reassign to `x` when using `:=` as this is assigning by reference into `x`. I would also not be using `subset` or `$` with data.tables as this is avoiding all the `data.table` efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reassign to x when using `:=` as this is assigning by reference into x (especially from version 1.8.3 where it will not print by default). I would also not be using subset or `$`with data.tables as this is avoiding all the data.table efficiency. –

Try something like this

```
 x <- data.table(x)
 # add a column that is the by-process mean
 x[, mean_duration := mean(Duration), by = Process]

 # calculate the difference
 x[, diff_duration := Duration - mean_duration]

 # subset just the 1st of august
 x[Date==as.Date("2012-08-01")]
```

This final subset could be done more efficiently if the `data.table` was keyed by `Date`. In the current form this final step is a vector scan, but a single vector scan should not be too inefficient.

I would recommend reading the introduction vignette to better utilize the data.table syntax and efficiency.